# How to take the mean of each hour for several days independently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mean

I have data taken every 15 minutes each day for a month. I want to find the mean of every hour within each day independently of the other days (so I can't group them by hours and take the mean because it will combine all the days together).
[Here is a sample of the data for one day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntl5q.png) So I want to take the mean for the first hour on the first day, then the mean for the next hour, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). On that note, it'd help to provide a [mre] including enough code to reproduce the problem as well as desired output. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) for specifics. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved by using [pandas.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html).
It provides functionality to group and aggregate data according to a selected interval.

Note the example, the data is similar to what you described (for simplicity only from two consecutive days and from two hours however the solution is general).

```
                  date  value
0  2022-02-11 13:12:00      2
1  2022-02-11 13:27:00      4
2  2022-02-11 13:43:00      7
3  2022-02-11 13:58:00      6
4  2022-02-11 14:13:00     11
5  2022-02-11 14:28:00      3
6  2022-02-11 14:44:00      5
7  2022-02-11 14:59:00      4
8  2022-02-12 13:12:00      1
9  2022-02-12 13:27:00      6
10 2022-02-12 13:43:00      7
11 2022-02-12 13:58:00      3
12 2022-02-12 14:13:00      1
13 2022-02-12 14:28:00     13
14 2022-02-12 14:44:00     11
15 2022-02-12 14:59:00      2
```

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60min', key='date')).mean().dropna()
```

```
                     value
date                      
2022-02-11 13:00:00   4.75
2022-02-11 14:00:00   5.75
2022-02-12 13:00:00   4.25
2022-02-12 14:00:00   6.75
```

The mean value for 2022-02-11 13:00:00 is taken from values: 2, 4, 6, 7 which all belongs to the interval between 13:00 - 13:59 that day. In result you get mean value per day per hour independently.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling) to hourly. Something like `df.resample('H').mean()` should work.